# "A beggar can never be bankrupt" proverb usage?

Tags: phrase-usage, proverbs

When is it used when someone says this English proverb:

> A beggar can never be bankrupt.

Apparently, it implies that a beggar is someone who never does any effort but why can they never be bankrupt?! The word "bankrupt" is most likely a negative adjective and being bankrupt could never occur for a beggar! That's obviously true because "a beggar never tries"! Is it sarcasm?

Comment: It's probably used in a situation when one has nothing to lose (a beggar presumably has not much money to lose and become bankrupt).

Comment: Thanksa a lot dear @alwayslearning for your quick response! but you says "probably" I need more certain answer for its definition and usage?

Comment: Oh! thanks dear @Drew! for your reference either! so could you give it as an answer for its reuse in future.

Comment: Did you try to find an answer for yourself before asking here? Just Googling the phrase gives several articles that explain the meaning of this proverb and how it’s used.

Comment: If you had looked up _bankrupt_, you would have found that the primary meaning is 'unable to pay what you owe, and having had control of your financial matters given, by a law court, to a person who sells your property to pay your debts_ {[CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bankrupt)}. A beggar would never have 'control of their financial affairs' and is most unlikely to have been lent anything. // The broadened sense here is that when you're at the bottom (of the situation being looked at), you can't fall any lower.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth! yeah! apparently you're right! this meaning is more likely! "A beggar would never control of his financial affairs" ! If not, this proverb would be written be something like : " A beggar could never be something more that a beggar" !

Comment: The reason behind this proverb is that a beggar won't have debts because "only the rich get credit" (*another proverb*).

Comment: Thanks @Graffito! so in another way it implies that a beggar won't have debts and won't be in charge of his financial affairs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @Amin's request to post as an answer:

[*When you got nothing, you got nothing to lose*](http://bobdylan.com/songs/rolling-stone/) -- Bob Dylan

Answer (score 0):

No matter how much you try to demean and destroy the motivation of a learned student, yet you should know, that a beggar can never be bankrupt

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Comments are restricted to the comments section below the question. If you need assistance in drafting an answer, please consult our [Help page on "Writing a good answer":](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)